# Correct and simple way to convert PNG to SVG?

Tags: vector, svg

What would be the best way to convert this type of image to SVG?

[image]

Comment: *Best* according to which criterion? Speed, quality, …?

Comment: @xenoid yes it can using the trace method in Illustrator as it's mentioned in the answer.  Are you aware that a "vector" can be exported in Illustrator as an SVG?

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate because the linked question is a starting point to answer your question.  While it may not be the best and may not answer your question I'd ask you make an [edit] telling us what software you have and what you've attempted so we can provide you with answers that may help you in the end.

Comment: I recommend https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:SVG#Converting_to_SVG and https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Vector_graphics_tutorial

Answer (score 8):

I copied your image to Inkscape and went to `Path > Trace Bitmap`. The settings = default.

Done.

SVG is Inkscape's native file type.

[image]

Because it's now a vector, the fill and stroke could be changed in a second.

Side by side comparison original vs. SVG does not show any serious differences except my random color selection:

[image]

NOTE: Your image is easily traceable because all borders are crisp and there's not much different colors. Tracing for example ordinary photos is quite unuseful except for weird posterization effects. Having only few colors with sharp borders goes well.

Comment: +1 for Inkscape... Another way it Open in Gimp, Select the black (Select by color tool),  and `Select>To path` and then export the produced path to SVG.

Comment: @xenoid  I have not tried it. That method earns to be an answer. If you write it with an example that shows the result is high quality and the needed parameters, I at least will upvote it.

Comment: Well, you get no "fill" that way, so I won't make a full answer about it. As far as I can tell the resulting path is a bit simpler (around 200 nodes in Gimp v.s. 285 in Inkscape) but there are several tiny extras "islets" (bug?) and a few minor "notches" in the outline.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, it **can't** be done.

Since PNG is *raster image* while SVG is *vector* (in the name ***S***calable **V**ector **G**raphics)
<sub>You can't actually convert a *raster* to *vector*</sub>

---

However, what you could do is Trace the image into Vector (SVG)

- Trace the Image in Illustrator (using the auto-trace feature)
- then save the traced output as SVG.